# Using the Virial Theorem to determine where the most massive stars reside in a star cluster

Tags: astrophysics, virial-theorem

I have come across a questions which I am unsure of. It asks to use the virial theorem to determine where the most massive stars reside in a star cluster. My approach is as follows:

Virial theorm:
$$2K + U = 0$$

$(1/2)mv^2$ is kinetic energy, on average larger mass objects will have more kinetic energy therefore the potential energy will be more negative therefore the higher mass stars will be in the centre of clusters.

The point saying "larger mass objects will have more kinetic energy" doesn't sit right with me as I am unsure if velocity is dependant on mass in this situation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the theorem, but that equation looks like it expresses radius as a function of velocity and nothing else. 2K = -U, solve, $r = GM/v^2$ where $M$ is the mass of the cluster and $r$ is the distance to the center of mass, irrespective of the mass of the object in question.